# Forge Viewer stopped working on Edge Update (Version 114.0.1823.37: June 2, 2023)

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are using this methodology to via dwf preview without conversion in Forge Viewer (https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/tree/experiment/pdf),

In the last update of Edge (Version 114.0.1823.37: June 2, 2023), the Viewer does not show the visualization of the models

The main alterations are related to policy on Edge Update.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-relnote-stable-channel#version-1140182337-june-2-2023

It is possible that the Forge Viewer API has not implemented the Workspace alterations.

Comment: Given that you've linked to an experimental branch that doesn't appear to have been updated in over 2 years, it's quite likely that it has not been updated!

Comment: The above mentioned link is just to mention the file reading procedure. When API is used, updated as follows below: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css and https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought that was a dependency!

Comment: Does this API have the same issue in other browsers like Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: For the latest Chrome update it also stopped working. However for Firefox the API continues to work.

In this case I have a development based on Edge.

Comment: Does it happen for one specific DWF? Which Version of Viewer you're using?

Comment: The problem occurs with all dwg files after the Edge update.

Comment: Could you please show us the error messages in DevTools console if you could find any error message there? By the way, you can upgrade to the latest version of Microsoft Edge now.